# Folland's ''Real Analysis'': Proving the Chain Rule.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In Folland's *Real Analysis, Second Edition*, he proves the chain rule as Proposition 3.9:

''Suppose that $\nu$ is a $\sigma$-finite signed measure and $\mu, \lambda$ are $\sigma$-finite measures on $(X, \scr{M})$ such that $\nu < \!\! < \mu$ and $\mu < \!\! < \lambda$.

*a.*  If $g \in L^1(\nu)$, then $g(d\nu / d\mu) \in L^1(\mu)$ and

\begin{equation} \int g d\nu = \int g \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}. \end{equation}

*b.*  We have $\nu < \!\! < \mu$, and

\begin{equation} \frac{d\nu}{d\lambda} = \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda} \;\;\;\; \mu-\text{a.e.''} \end{equation}

Assume that (a) has been proven.  In Folland's proof of (b), he immediately asks the reader to set $g = \chi_E (d\nu / d\mu)$, in preparation to use (a), where $E \in \scr{M}$ is arbitrary.

**My question is this:**  In the case that $|\nu|(E) = \infty$, how do we know that $g \in L^1(\mu)$, as the hypotheses of (a) demands.  Of course, if it were the case that $|\nu|(E) < \infty$, then $\chi_E \in L^1(\nu)$ and so $g \in L^1(\mu)$ by applying (a) to $g' = \chi_E$.  But in the case that $|\nu|(E) = \infty$, it seems that we must rely on the $\sigma$-finiteness of $\nu$ to show $g \in L^1(\mu)$.

I am fairly sure that this is a straightforward application of the definitions plus the MCT (or some variant of this idea), but I have not been able to put the pieces together correctly, it seems.  Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't exactly answer the question directly, but it sufficed for me.

An excellent proof of this chain rule that completely avoids the roadblock discussed in my original question can be found here:

http://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2010/07/12/the-radon-nikodym-chain-rule/

Answer (score 1):

The following is the original proof in Folland:

[image]

Note that in the beginning of the proof, we have the assumption that $\nu\geq 0$. In the case that $\nu(E)=\infty$ (with assumption $\nu\geq 0$), instead of showing $g=\chi_E(d\nu/d\mu)$ is in $L^1(\mu)$, one needs to use the $\sigma$-finiteness to reduce the proof to the finite case.